# How to read a json file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json

I have a configuration json file in my application.

```
{
 "Name":{
     "Catgory":{
        "Val":{
           "Gaby": "122"
         },
        "Batch":{
            "Hede" : "86"
         }
       }
    }
 }
```

I have lot of configurations like the above. But when I try to read that like below, I'm unable to do.

```
I have imported the file as config in the current file. When I try to read as below I'm able to get the values.

config.Name.Catgory.Val
```

But in place of Val,if I try to get the value dynamically like

```
configVal = "Val"

And if I try to call,

config.Name.Catgory.configVal I'm unable to read. Can anyone please help me with this?
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [bracket-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) in order to access values dynamically:

```js
const config = {
 "Name":{
     "Catgory":{
        "Val":{
           "Gaby": "122"
         },
        "Batch":{
            "Hede" : "86"
         }
       }
    }
 }
 
 let configVal = 'Val';
 console.log(config.Name.Catgory[configVal]);
```